# React Router Error - Cannot GET [Page Name]

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As I am digging into React I am finding a need for the router. I am following along with Wes Bos' video series but am hitting a snag when I try to access any route other than my root.

```
import ReactRouter from 'react-router';
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
```

Then my router

```
var routes = (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
    <Route path="/details" component={DetailsPage} />
    <Route path="*" component={LoginPage} />
  </Router>
);
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('content'));
```

However, if I go to localhost:3000/dashboard I am given the error:

```
Cannot GET /dashboard
```

Any advice?

Comment: how is your backend server set up?  With browser history you have to make changes to the backend routes as well.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add this to webpack.config.js

```
  devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Comment: this is the answer. @Yuschick you should accept it to help people looking at this problem quickly identify the solution.

Comment: For me it didn't work. Now I am getting the error: `Cannot GET /`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped me.

Comment: @AbhaySood found this from the website (http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html): 

`historyApiFallback: false,
  // Set this as true if you want to access dev server from arbitrary url.
  // This is handy if you are using a html5 router.`

Comment: It's more instructive to tell people the "why" not just the "how".

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure your server appropriately when using browser history: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server.

If you're using the webpack dev server, enable `historyApiFallback`.

Comment: "If you're using the webpack dev server, enable historyApiFallback."

This fixed the issue for me.